# How to add variables in *.libraries.yml in drupal 8

Tags: 8

I need to convert the below code added in hook_page_attachments()
 and
 add the external js in *.libraries.yml but not sure how to add variables like 
$token and $user->mail in the *.libraries.yml so I can just attach library

```
   drupal_add_js('http://js.acobot.com/' . check_plain($token) . '.js', 'external');
    $script = 'var _aco = _aco || [];';
    drupal_add_js($script, array('type' => 'inline', 'scope' => 'footer'));
    if ($user->uid) {
      $user_info = "_aco.push(['email', '" . check_plain($user->mail) . "']);";
      drupal_add_js($user_info, array('type' => 'inline', 'scope' => 'footer'));
    }
```

Add Your Script to a file
In *.libraries.yml, I have added

```
acobot-initialise:
  version: 1.x
  js:
    js/acobot.js: {}
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery
    - core/drupalSettings
```

Added that file to the library under

> $attachments['#attached']['library'][] =
>   'acobot/acobot-initialise';

Use drupalSettings to pass data from php to js

```
  $attachments['#attached']['drupalSettings']['acobot']['email'] = check_plain($account->getEmail());
```

Added script acobot.js as follows

> (function ($, Drupal, drupalSettings) {
>
> 'use strict';
>
> Drupal.behaviors.acobot = {
>       attach: function (context, settings) {
>             var _aco = _aco || [];
>             _aco.push(['email', drupalSettings.acobot.email]);
>       }   };
>
> })(jQuery, Drupal, drupalSettings);

Comment: You can’t - add your script to a file, and add that file to your library, then use `drupalSettings` to pass data from php to js

Comment: @clive, I have tried to follow your comments, if possible can you validate if what I have implemented is matching as per your recommendations

Comment: You can do that better than I can - execute the code, and see the results

Answer (score 2):

First add your acobot script inline:

```
function mymodule_page_attachments(array &$attachments) {
  $attachments['#attached']['html_head'][] = [
    // The data.
    [
      '#type' => 'html_tag',
      // The HTML tag to add, in this case a  tag.
      '#tag' => 'script',
      // The value of the HTML tag, here we want to end up with
      // alert("Hello world!");.
      '#value' => 'alert("Hello world!");',
      // Set attributes like src to load a file.
      '#attributes' => array('src' => 'http://js.acobot.com/' . check_plain($token) . '.js'),

    ],
    // A key, to make it possible to recognize this HTML  element when altering.
    'hello-world',
  ];
}
```

next add your library with *.js file where you can call push method

```
cuddly-slider:
  version: 1.x
  js:
    js/cuddly-slider.js: {}
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery
    - core/drupalSettings
```

and pass user mail to  drupalSettings.

```
$build['#attached']['drupalSettings']['fluffiness']['cuddlySlider']['foo'] = 'user mail here';
```

All examples are available here https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules/adding-stylesheets-css-and-javascript-js-to-a-drupal-8-module

Comment: Hi @lamp5 , how can I convert 
1)     $script = 'var _aco = _aco || [];';
    drupal_add_js($script, array('type' => 'inline', 'scope' => 'footer'));
2)        $user_info = "_aco.push(['email', '" . check_plain($account->getEmail()) . "']);";
      drupal_add_js($user_info, array('type' => 'inline', 'scope' => 'footer'));
to drupal 8 , I am still not clear actually,help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The biggest issue I see here is the hyphen in your library name. I haven't figured out how to escape the hyphen in the library name when passing the name of a library to drupalSettings so I will instead use an underscore or join the words. In this case the library name would be acobot_initialise or acobotinitialise. In this example use the underscore so to begin, change your library name to acobot_initialise.

You need to add your variable(s) to drupalSettings and that is done in the preprocess of the entity you are working with. It could be a node or a paragraph or some other entity in which case you'll use hook_preprocess() in your_module.module file. In your example, it would look like the following:

```
function mymodule_preprocess(&$variables, $hook, $info) {
  // Add code to expose $account->getEmail() to this code block
  $computed_settings = [
    "acobotemail" => check_plain($account->getEmail());,
    "anothervariable" => "a variable you want to pass to the js file";,      
  ];
  $build['#attached']['library'][] = 'acobot/acobot_initialise';
  $build['#attached']['drupalSettings']['acobot']['acobot_initialise'] = $computed_settings;
}
```

Then you need to expose drupalSettings to your JS file, acobot.js. You will do this as follows:

```
(function ($, Drupal, drupalSettings) {
  Drupal.behaviors.Acobot = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {
      var acobotemail = drupalSettings.acobot.acobot_initialise.acobotemail;
      var anothervariable = drupalSettings.acobot.acobot_initialise.anothervariable;
      // Do Some stuff with the variables acobotemail and anothervariable.
    }
  }
})(jQuery, Drupal, drupalSettings);
```